# How to number rows with a repeating 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4,... series

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, window-functions

How can I add a series in length of 4 to a table like this:

Source table:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Results table:

```
id    series
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     1
6     2
7     3
8     4
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: +1 included sample data, expected results, and PostgreSQL version. It's a weird question and I can't imagine why you'd want to, but hey...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your IDs are really consecutive and gapless, you can just use `id % 4 + 1`. But I imagine that in reality your IDs aren't so orderly, and if they're generated from a `SEQUENCE` you shouldn't rely on them being gapless.

You can do it properly with `row_number()`, as shown here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/22767/5

```
SELECT 
  id,
  (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 4 + 1
FROM Table1
ORDER BY 1;
```

It's also possible to do using `generate_series` as a set-returning-function in the `SELECT` list, but that's a PostgreSQL extension, wheras the above is standard SQL that'll work in any modern database except MySQL, which doesn't support window functions.

If you want to actually add a column to the table it gets a bit more complicated. I'm not really sure why you'd want to do that, but it's possible using `UPDATE ... FROM`:

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN col2 INTEGER;

WITH gen_num(id,n) AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 4 + 1
    FROM Table1
    ORDER BY 1)
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = n
FROM gen_num
WHERE gen_num.id = table1.id;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: "and if they're generated from a SEQUENCE you shouldn't rely on them being gapless." why? :(

Comment: @Ali See the documentation for `nextval`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html . Basically, entries generated from a sequence are not re-used if a transaction rolls back. Other considerations here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: what's the meaning of '%'? remainder ?

Comment: @Ali It's the modulus operator. See the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html